# Spark and sharded JDBC datasources

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, apache-spark

I have a production sharded cluster of PostgreSQL machines where sharding is handled at the application layer. (Created records are assigned a system generated unique identifier - not a UUID - which includes a 0-255 value indicating the shard # that record lives on.) This cluster is replicated in RDS so large read queries can be executed against it.

I'm trying to figure out the best option for accessing this data within Spark.

I was thinking of creating a small dataset (a text file) that contains only the shard names, i.e., `integration-shard-0`, `integration-shard-1`, etc. Then I'd partition this dataset across the Spark cluster so ideally each worker would only have a single shard name (but I'd have to handle cases where a worker has more than one shard). Then when I create a `JdbcRDD` I'd actually create 1..*n* such RDDs, one for each shard name residing on that worker, and merge the resulting RDDs together.

This seems like it would work but before I go down this path I wanted to see how other people have solved similar problems.

(I also have a separate Cassandra cluster available as second datacenter for analytic processing which I will be accessing with Spark.)

Comment: Have you thought about implementing your own RDD that overrides [`preferredLocations()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) and allocating each Spark partition to a shard?

Comment: I did implement my own RDD that overwrites `getPartitions` I'll post a link to the gist below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing my own `ShardedJdbcRDD` for which the preliminary version can be found at the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/cfeduke/3bca88ed793ddf20ea6d

At the time I wrote it, this version doesn't support use from Java, only Scala. (I may update it.) It also doesn't have the same sub-partitioning scheme that `JdbcRDD` has, for which I will eventually create an overload constructor. Basically `ShardedJdbcRDD` will query your RDBMS shards across the cluster; if you have at least as many Spark slaves as shards, each slave will get one shard for its partition.

A future overloaded constructor will support the same range query that `JdbcRDD` has so if there are more Spark slaves in the cluster than shards the data can be broken up into smaller sets through range queries.

Comment: Are the shards collocated with the spark nodes or are they one a different set of machines?

Comment: Different set of machines (AWS RDS replica) so data locality isn't necessary. I'll look at creating a version of this that supports data locality when I get more experienced with working with Spark. (Our production cluster will have data locality with a replicated Cassandra data center.)

Comment: Gotcha.  I bet you'll get more than decent performance as it is.